# Prime-NG Confirm Dialog does not work in a service

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I just noticed a strange behavior of PrimeNG's Confirm Dialog. In  test.component.html, there is an Input Field. It checks if the typed in value is greater than 150. If it is greater, then a Confirm Button shows up below the Input Field ("Please confirm"). Clicking it shows a Dialog with Yes and No.

The Confirm Button shall vanish after choosing either Yes or No.

**Now here's the problem:**
Vanishing only works if the confirm method is called directly in test.component.ts. I'd like to extract it into a service (customConfirmation.service.ts), but the vanishing does not work there. Do you know why? I have got absolutely no idea. ("this.messagesWeightTest" and the button vanishing do not work.)

**test.component.html**

```
<div class="p-col-12 p-md-6 p-lg-5">
  Weight:
  <div class="ui-inputgroup">
    <input pInputText type="number" id="weight" name="weight" [(ngModel)]="newTest.testWeight"
           placeholder="---">
    <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">kg</span>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="validateIfWeightOutsideRange()">
    <div>
      <p-confirmDialog key="confirmWeightTest"></p-confirmDialog>
      <button type="button" (click)="confirmWeightTest()" pButton icon="pi pi-check"
              label="Please confirm!">
      </button>
      <p-messages [value]="messagesWeightTest"></p-messages>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

It seems that the whole "accept" and "reject" do not work:

**customConfirmation.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {SessionService} from "./session.service";
import {ConfirmationService, Message} from "primeng/api";

@Injectable()
export class CustomConfirmationService {

    messagesWeightTest: Message[] = [];
    weightConfirmed: boolean = false;

    constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {}

      confirmWeightTest() {

        this.confirmationService.confirm({
          message: 'Are you sure?',
          header: 'Confirmation',
          icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
          key: 'confirmWeightTest',
          accept: () => {
            this.messagesWeightTest = [{
              severity: 'info', summary: 'Confirmed', detail: 'The input is correct.'}];
          this.weightConfirmed = true;
          },
          reject: () => {
            this.sessionService.newTest.testWeight = null;
        this.weightConfirmed = true;
          }
        });
      }
}
```

test.component.ts just calls the confirmation method from the service:

**test.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Injectable, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ConfirmationService, Message, SelectItem} from "primeng/api";
import {trigger, state, style, transition, animate} from '@angular/animations';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {CustomConfirmationService} from "../services/customConfirmation.service";
import {ValidationService} from "../services/validation.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private customConfirmationService: CustomConfirmationService,
              private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
              private validationService: ValidationService) {

}

ngOnInit() {}

  // Confirmations for ConfirmDialogs

  confirmWeightTest() {
    this.customConfirmationService.confirmWeightTest();
  }

  // Validations for ConfirmDialogs --> work!

  validateIfWeightOutsideRange() {
    return !!this.validationService.validateIfWeightOutsideRange();
  }
```

Again, if I copy and paste confirmWeightTest() from customConfirmation.service.ts into test.component.ts, everything works fine. I also tested this with another project.

I would be glad if you could tell me whats going on here.

Please also refer to [Prime-NG Confirm Dialog: Hide the Button after Confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831431/prime-ng-confirm-dialog-hide-the-button-after-confirmation)

I implemented everything as recommended in the answer to this question. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an error in your console ? Can you create a StackBlitz please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdsngr) and everything work as well

You need to declare **CustomConfirmationService** in providers and update

```
<p-messages [(value)]="messagesWeightTest"></p-messages>
```

to

```
<p-messages [(value)]="customConfirmationService.messagesWeightTest"></p-messages>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. Yes, with the messages, your approach works. But the "Please confirm" button still stays, even after choosing "yes" or "no" in the dialog. Instead, it shall disappear. Is there a possibility to achieve this?

Comment: I updated stackblitz. You can use "confirming" variable to hide "Please confirm" button